# React Native | Android Studio

Tags: react-native, android-studio

how can I install back my project application on an emulator using React Native, I tried to
uninstall my application on the emulator (Android Studio), and when I use

```
npx react-native run-android
```

again, it cannot start.

Answer (score 0):

If you have set up Android Studio and NodeJS correctly you can Create an Emulator.

After that open your code and the Emulator and then go for this commands:

```
npm react-native start
```

and when the Metro Bundler has started succesfully in a new Terminal in VSCode for example.

```
npm react-native run-android
```

NPX stands for Execute so it always downloads what it needs before running the command if you have set up everything use NPM instead of NPX.